# Error: in JAR with mysql-connector-java-5.0.7-bin

Tags: java, mysql, jar

I have created Simple java application in netbeans IDE. i have used **mysql-connector-java-5.0.7-bin** to connect java with mysql.it works fine in IDE
 finally i have created **executable jar.**. when i run the jar file from cmd window i got the following error in **cmd**

```
db not connected -connectionjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Dr
ver
db not connected -connectionjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Dr
ver
connecting to the database
Invalid userjava.lang.NullPointerException
db not closedjava.lang.NullPointerException
its is from else
```

can any one help me to solve this one?

Answer (score 1):

It was not possible to create a database connection with the given parameters.
 Please check the Exception below. There can be two reasons for this error: •Your database is down, or
•Your database is not accessible with the given connection parameters.
Be also aware that Alkacon recommends to use the following JDBC drivers for MySQL 4.1.x & 5.0.x:
[mysql-connector-java-5.0.7-bin.jar]
Check that the Jdbc drivers are included in your class path.

Error connecting to database using: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/".

---

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2748) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1553) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at org.opencms.setup.CmsSetupDb.setConnection(CmsSetupDb.java:480) at org.apache.jsp.setup.step_005f4a_005fdatabase_005fvalidation_jsp._jspService(step_005f4a_005fdatabase_005fvalidation_jsp.java:93) at

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.7-bin.jar` to your [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) when running your application.
The class path is the path that the Java runtime environment searches for classes and other resource files. The classpath can be set using either the `-classpath` option when calling a JDK tool (the preferred method) or by setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.
For example:

```
java -classpath mysql-connector-java-5.0.7-bin.jar;. com.foo.Main
```